# Convert FTP to SFTP in vb6

Tags: ftp, sftp, vb6

I have to convert FTP code to SFTP in vb6. I am really new to it so have little idea. 
So to get started I have few questions:

1. Are FTP and SFTP servers different. I have a host name for eg. example.com, currently when we do FTP, URL is formed as ftp://example.com. So is this example.com, a FTP server or can we use it for SFTP also?
2. If it's an FTP as well as SFTP server that's fine. But if not then will we require a new server or this FTP server can be converted to SFTP server?

Comment: What's your on topic question exactly?  You can't use code meant for an unencrypted connection for a encrypted connection.  You have to handle the encryption and the code your using doesn't handle it currently

Comment: `ftp` and `sftp` are completely unrelated protocols.  `sftp` access is most frequently provided by installing and configuring OpenSSH.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands your question would also be closed on [SO].

Comment: I got it from the answer of dsolimano.
I just wanted to know that can FTP and SFTP be on the same server.

Comment: Of course you can they are unrelated to one another

Answer (score 1):

To answer briefly, user4556274 is correct in pointing out that they're unrelated protocols.

For "Are FTP and SFTP servers different", the answer is, they can be.  My company's FTP server is ftp.example.com, and our sftp server is sftp.example.com, or it could be secure.example.com, or anything else.  Or they could be the same.  That's up to the server owner.

For "will we require a new server" that is entirely up to the server owner as well.